# Unable to set JVM settings with JKube Maven plugin

Tags: kubernetes, jkube

I'm trying to pass the JVM settings to a Java application which is configured to use JKube Maven plugin to deploy on Openshift. I've added in deployment.yaml file the following settings:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
          value: '-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:MetaspaceSize=128M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m'
```

When the Java process is started in a Pod, I can see that Java_OPTS are overwritten by the default values (see the second setting for **-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize**):

```
DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) VM Arguments: -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:MetaspaceSize=128M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=100m -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError
```

That eventually results in:

```
Terminating due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
```

Can you recommend a way to set correctly the JVM settings when using JKube Maven plugin?
Thanks

Comment: do you have something like this in your Dockerfile CMD or entrypoint to pass the JAVA_OPTS to jvm `java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar <your_jar_name>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the GC_MAX_METASPACE_SIZE environment variable to define the maximum size of the Metaspace. For example:

```
- name: GC_MAX_METASPACE_SIZE
  value: 256
```

Specifically, there's an example here: [how to set the METASPACE size on Kubernetes/OpenShift](http://www.mastertheboss.com/other/java-stuff/solving-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-metaspace-error) using JKube